# CCAvenue Transaction Error. Error Code: -1, Error Description: Null Pointer Exception

Tags: php, yii, ccavenue

I have integrated CCAvenue to my website done in `php Yii framework` .The transaction works perfectly in 95% cases but sometimes I'm getting an error like this.I have searched in google and ccavenue docs, but didn't find any clue.Please help me.

```
Error Code: -1
Error Description:Null+Pointer+Exception%21%21%21
```

Comment: This is error returned by java from service you are connecting to. It is similar to php "Call to a member function on a non-object". You have to ask CCAvenue what went wrong.

Comment: @PeterM  Already Contacted them.I didn't get a reply from them.Any Alternatives?

Comment: You could log entire requests which fail and check if you have all parts of request properly build. Maybe some subobject is missing? Provided error message is meaningless and generic.

Comment: If anything is missing,it will show the error at 1st step,ie when we posting values to cc avenue.I'm getting error after completing transaction.Also I have logged that values,it's fine.

Comment: Then it's CCAvenue issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed that it's the problem with CCAvenue. There is nothing to do in our end.

Answer (score 0):

Well am not so well versed with the scripting errors but I encountered this issue while making payment on one of the portals. Here is my observations on it.

While attempting to make payment using 'Master card', the error was frequent.

I tried adjusting the strings (like commas, space etc) in all the information I had filled but to no avail.

Hence I changed the credit card from Master card to VISA card and this change of card led to successful processing.

I wonder if this is in any relevance, with your query. But I assure you the error is same as yours.